# Understanding _.each on backbone collections

Tags: backbone.js, underscore.js

Warning: I'm a backbone newbie.

I'm iterating over all the models in my collection and rendering them. Simple enough, however, I wanted to make sure I understand well how this works. Here's what I have -

#### Model:

```
File = Backbone.Model.extend({});
```

#### Collection

```
Folder = Backbone.Collection.extend({ model: File });
```

#### ModelView

```
FileView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
       _.bindAll(this, 'render');
       this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.template = _.template(document.getElementById("fileTemplate").innerHTML);
        this.$el.html(this.template({ fileName: this.model.get("FileName") }));
    }   
})
```

#### CollectionView

```
FolderView = Backbone.View.extend({    
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {
        _(this.collection.models).each(function(file) {
            var fileView = new FileView({ model: file});
            this.$el.append(fileView.el);            
        },this); <--???
    }
});
```

This works perfectly fine. My question is about the _.each in my FolderView. Why do I have to pass the ***this*** back to my each loop?
If I don't pass ***this***, it refers to my window object instead of my collection. I know it's necessary to pass it, i just don't know why.

Comment: It's to insure that `this` means the same thing inside the context of the callback as it does at the `each` call site.

Comment: Don't use _.each to iterate over a collection's models. Every collection already comes with an 'each' method that is basically underscore's method. So, `this.collection.each(function () {}, this);` is what you want to use.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> `_.each(list, iterator, [context]) Alias: forEach`
>
> Iterates over a list of elements, yielding each in turn to an iterator function. The iterator is bound to the context object, if one is passed. Each invocation of iterator is called with three arguments: (element, index, list). If list is a JavaScript object, iterator's arguments will be (value, key, list). Delegates to the native forEach function if it exists.
>
> [underscore docs#each](http://underscorejs.org/#each)

The default context is the window object.  By setting `this` to be the context, you are making `this` in the function map to `this` where the function was called.

See the following for reference on this topic:

- [A bit about function contexts](http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2009/02/09/javascript-5-ways-to-call-a-function.aspx)
- [underscore source for _.each](http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html#section-15)
- [ForEach docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [Strict vs non-strict context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FFunctions_and_function_scope%2FStrict_mode)

Comment: the 1st link "A bit about function contexts" was very useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

To explain you need to first realize that in JavaScript only a function creates a new scope (that's right a loop doesn't actual create a new scope) and that unlike some other languages the context of that scope is mutable, meaning depending on how it's called the *this* within that scope might refer to different things.

As a result of this a common problem that arises is that you might have a inner and outer function and within the inner function you want to refer to the scope of the outer function but the inner function has changed the scope so that `this` no longer refers to the outer function.

In order to handle this we need to make sure that we save the context of the outer function (have a look at the [following](http://joshuakehn.com/2011/10/20/Understanding-JavaScript-Context.html) for a more detailed explanation).

A common pattern you might see in JavaScript is assigning the context (`this`) to a variable and then using that within the function.

For example your render function could technically have been rewritten as the following

```
 render: function () {
       var self = this; 
        _(this.collection.models).each(function(file) {
            var fileView = new FileView({ model: file});
            self.$el.append(fileView.el);            
        });
    }
```

Now that we provided a basic understanding of the `this` and `context` we can turn to the `_.each` function from [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org), [_.each](http://underscorejs.org/#each) like most of the functions in underscore.js take an optional third parameter which refers to the context which underscore.js then uses so that you can conveniently refer to that context.

Underscore.js also provides a utility function  [bind](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) to bind a context to a function.

Comment: EcmaScript 5 also provides a native `bind` method that doesn't require third-party libraries, assuming you're not targeting legacy browsers.  jQuery also provides a `$.proxy(fn, context)` method that does the same thing.  I've actually found that jQuery's `proxy` method is less brittle than the native implementation.  For example, we had a backbone view that was extending a base view class, and we tried using doing `events: { 'click #someId': aFnOnTheBaseClass.bind(this) }` with no luck. Switched it to `$.proxy(aFnOnTheBaseClass, this)` instead and it worked great.

Comment: @Isochronous The reason I mentioned underscore's `.bind` is because the question is specifically about underscore.js and what's the use of passing in `this` to it's `each` method.

Comment: Yeah, I got that, I just wanted to make sure he was aware that underscore isn't required to achieve the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

The original question was, "Why do I have to override "this" in the each(fn, this) call?"

You are creating an anonymous function for the first parameter. By default, "this" inside a function refers to the object holding the reference to the function through which the call was made. Your anonymous function is created against the root context object, which is window in a browser. That's what you are observing when you don't supply an object for the second parameter.

each() has the ability to determine if you passed a different object to serve as "this" within the function. each() can then use Object.bind() or Object.call(), both of which use the first parameter passed to them to override "this".

Passing "this" as the second parameter to each() causes the outer function's context object to be used as "this" in the inner function.